# Lumen Dingo Route:list

Tags: laravel, list, api, routes, lumen

Installed Dingo framework in my lumen project 5.5 before that i was able to run and view all routes using the normal artisan command artisan route:list. After installing Dingo the route list shows just an empty list [screenshot of route-list results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuiLO.png). I am presuming dingo has handles its own routes list section on its own. I have installed a couple of packages and i think they aren't compatible with lumen5.5. Is there any other way i can run and view my routes still using dingo. Any help will be honestly appreciated